# column with dates into datetime index in dask

Tags: pandas, dask

```
pd.DatetimeIndex(df_dask_dataframe['name_col'])
```

I have a dask dataframe for which I want to convert a column with dates into datetime index. However I get a not implemented error. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need [`dask.dataframe.DataFrame.set_index`](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html?highlight=set_index#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.set_index) if `dtype` of column is `datetime64`:

```
df_dask_dataframe = df_dask_dataframe.set_index('name_col')
```

Comment: @jezrael, thanks for the answer, I did not downvote.